# AFrame content not rendering on Chrome with hyperHTML

Tags: javascript, three.js, single-page-application, aframe, hyperhtml

A-Frame content does not render on Chrome while it renders on FireFox and Safari.

As per [CodePen here](https://codepen.io/jbremmer/pen/xXmZgJ)
const { hyper, wire } = hyperHTML;

```
class Box extends hyper.Component {

  render() { return this.html`
    <a-scene>
        <a-box color="red" position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2"></a-box>
    </a-scene>
  `;
  }
}

document.body.appendChild(new Box().render());
```

I'm sure I'm missing something, same content renders fine as static HTML in all browsers ([CodePen](https://codepen.io/jbremmer/pen/YrdwOK)).

```
<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-box color="red" position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2"></a-box>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: I've force-fixed the issue in *hyperHTML* even if it's about AFrame uaing Custom Elements V0. I will drop the force-fix once AFrame will migrate to V1.

Your Code Pen, and mine too, now works. Regards

---

I've [forked your pen](https://codepen.io/WebReflection/pen/xXMxEO?editors=0010) and written pretty much the same code:

```
const { hyper } = hyperHTML;

class Box extends hyper.Component {
  render() { return this.html`
    <a-scene>
          <a-box color="red"
            position="0 2 -5"
            rotation="0 45 45"
            scale="2 2 2"></a-box>
        </a-scene>`;
  }
}

hyper(document.body)`${new Box}`;
```

but I had to add a very ugly line at the end:

```
// if you comment this out nothing works
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
```

This is because AFrame uses a Custom Elements polyfill (actually mine) which does not seem to trigger the registry when it's cloned from a template node.

There is [a polyfill known issue](https://github.com/WebReflection/document-register-element/issues/92) that I've never been able to reproduce and this might be the use case I was looking for.

Unfortunately it seems that right now AFrame components might have troubles with hyperHTML.

My apologies, I'll try to fix this ASAP.

Comment: Update: Chrome is the only browser with a native V0 implementation of CustomElements and AFrame is using that implementation. This does not solve the issue but at least it explains why every other browser works without issues. It might be that AFrame needs to update their core but I'll come back on this ASAP. Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

just to clarify misunderstandings, it's been verified this is not a hyperHTML bug.

Writing the following

```
const scene = `<a-scene>
  <a-box color="red" position="0 2 -5" rotation="0 45 45" scale="2 2 2"></a-box>
</a-scene>`;

var template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = scene;
document.body.appendChild(template.content);
```

would fail as well, without including any extra library beside AFrame.

There is an ongoing investigation but what you should be aware of is that any library based on modern template element to produce generic content will fail with aframe 0.7 and only in Chrome.

**Update** [bug filed](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3182) in AFrame repository